# Empty reduce output while using Custom Partitioner in MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Problem Statement:

Input

> Monami 45000 A 
>       Tarun 34000 B
>       Riju 25000 C
>       Rita 42000 A
>       Mithun 40000 A
>       Archana 21000 C
>       Shovik 32000 B

I want to use Custom Partitioner in Mapreduce to separate employee records with grade A, B and C in three different output files.

Output 1

> Monami 45000 A
>       Rita 42000 A
>       Mithun 40000 A

Output 2

> Tarun 34000 B
>       Shovik 32000 B

Output 3

> Riju 25000 C
>       Archana 21000 C

Map Code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
//import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class Map 
            extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,Text>
{

//private Text key1 = new Text();
//private Text value1 = new Text();

@Override
protected void map(LongWritable key,Text value,Context context) 
                        throws IOException,InterruptedException
{   
    String line = value.toString();
    String[] part = line.split("\t");
    int len = part.length;

    //System.out.println(len);
    if (len == 3)
    {
        context.write(new Text(part[2]), new Text(part[0]+"\t"+part[1]));
        //System.out.println(part[0]+part[1]+part[2]);
    }

}
```

Partitioner Code

```
 import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
 import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Partitioner;

 public class CustomPartitioner
            extends Partitioner<Text,Text>
{
@Override
public int getPartition(Text key, Text value, int numReduceTasks)
    {
    if(numReduceTasks==0)
        return 0;
    if(key.equals(new Text("A")))
        return 0;
    if(key.equals(new Text("B")))
        return 1;
    else 
        return 2;
    }
    }
```

Reduce Code

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.Iterator;

 import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
 //import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
 import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

 public class Reduce 
                extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text>
 {

@Override
protected void reduce(Text key,Iterable<Text> values,Context context)
                                        throws IOException,InterruptedException
    {
        Iterator<Text> itr = values.iterator();

        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            context.write(new Text(itr.next().getBytes()),new Text(key));
        }


    }
   }
```

Driver Class

```
 import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
//import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;


public class MapReduceDriver
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Job job = new Job();

    job.setJarByClass(MapReduceDriver.class);
    job.setJobName("Custom Partitioner");

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job,new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,new Path(args[1]));

    job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job.setPartitionerClass(CustomPartitioner.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(3);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1);

}

}
```

The code runs without any errors but three reduce output files are empty. Also when the job runs, it shows map output bytes as zero. Hence I believe the map is not generating any key-value pairs. But I cannot find out the reason. Can you help me find the mistake?

Also I have one more confusion: In Map class, when variable `len` is checked for > 0, then I am getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException but it runs fine without any exception if checked with == 3. Why does it throw an exception with > 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your input data (as pasted here) is not tab-separated, but comma-separated. It should work fine, if you replace this line:

```
 String[] part = line.split("\t");
```

with this line:

```
String[] part = line.split(" ");
```

The reason you are getting an exception when you check for `len > 0` is that your string is not split into any sub-parts so `len` is 1. Then it satisfies the if condition and tries to execute something for the position 2 of parts, which does not exist.

In the existing code, `len` is not 3, so the code never enters the if block, hence, no exception thrown.